# Trying to display the information from the response but it won't show up. Using mongoose and nextjs (typescript)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js

Trying to display the information from the response but it won't show up. If I console log it i can see it in the terminal. how do i get it to show on the page? the response displays as an array

```
type Student = {
  _id: string;
  firstname: string;
  lastname: string;
  matricno: string;
};

function DashBoard() {
  const [student, setStudent] = useState<Student>();

  //this works
  // console.log(getCookie("user"))

  const showinfo = async () => {
    const token = getCookie('user');
    const body = {
      _id: token,
    };

    const response = (await fetch(
      'http://localhost:3000/api/student/fetchStudent',
      { method: 'POST', body: JSON.stringify(body) }
    ).then((res) => res.json())) as Student;

    console.log(JSON.stringify(response, ['student', 'firstname'])); //displays right information

    setStudent(response);

    const user = JSON.stringify(response, ['student', 'lastname']);

    console.log(user); //displays right information
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    showinfo();
  }, []);

  return (
    <StuLayout>
      <>
        <Header title='dashboard' />
        <div className='text-red-500 text-3xl'>
          welcome {student?.firstname}
        </div>
      </>
    </StuLayout>
  );
}

export default DashBoard;
```

Comment: It sounds like your api endpoint is returning an array. If so, you could instead return an object (the name 'fetchStudent' implies it'll only ever return a single student so this would prob make most sense). Alternatively, you can read the first student from the response with `setStudent(response[0])`.

Comment: Can you show the result of `console.log(response)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i had to restructure the api to specify the elements i needed

```
export default async function fetchStudent(req, res) {
if (req.method === "POST") {
    console.log('CONNECTING TO MONGO');
    await connectMongo();
    console.log('CONNECTED TO MONGO');

    const { _id } = JSON.parse(req.body)

    console.log('FETCHING DOCUMENTS');




    const student = await Student.findById(_id).select("lastname firstname ");

    console.log('FETCHED STUDENT');
    // console.log(student)
    return res.status(200).json({
        ...student._doc,

    })
}
else {

    return res.status(400).json({
        notFound: true,
    });

}
```

};